# on mouse click for any clicked object on stage, possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

i have mc with 10 objects instead of writting code for each i want same action prefermed on every clicked object with 1 code is there way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `MouseEvent.CLICK` on the stage, or on the parent movie clip, and the `event.target` variable will point to the object that was clicked:

```
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
     trace('clicked', event.target);
  });
```

Comment: the problem is that i need it only for objects inside sub MC that's on the main area, and this way seems to work for every object in movie

e.g. i goto frame 20 and it has this sub mc any this effect applied to all frame 20 and that mc, even though i type in inside mc.  other frames of main timeline are ok

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you only wanted it on a specific frame. Two thoughts: you could check `if (currentFrame == 20) { ... }` inside the listener, and only do the work if that's true. You also might be able to add the listener in the timeline script for that keyframe, but I'm not familiar enough with CS to say for sure.

Comment: frame if currentFrame == 1 (sub movie has 1 frame) still moves all objects on frame 20 of main timeline.

hmm i removed word stage. and it works now as intended!

Comment: You can add the listener to the sub MC instead of the stage, to only get events for children of that clip (e.g. `subMC.addEventListener(...)`).

Comment: does not work gives 1120: Access of undefined property sub_vid. but works if you put it inside sub mc withhout word stage. just addeventlistener ()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I fully understand what your question is, but you can use a for loop to iterate through a `DisplayObjectContainer` object's child `DisplayObject` objects. Then on each iteration you add an event listener to the current child `DisplayObject` object that listens for the `MouseEvent.Click` event.

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < displayObjectContainer.numChildren; i++)
{
    displayObjectContainer.getChildAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

}// end for

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // code to handle click event

}// end function
```